# Entity Framework 5 creating model from database, instantiate navigation properties in a constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I am trying to force entity framework 5.0 to create a constructor on each of my generated poco classes. This constructor should instantiate any foreign key navigation properties I have.

e.g.

```
public partial class Event
 {
    public System.Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string EventDesc { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsObsolete { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedUser { get; set; }
    public int RowVer { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

should become:

```
public partial class Event
 {
    public Event()
    {
         this.UserProfile = new UserProfile();
    }

    public System.Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string EventDesc { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsObsolete { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedUser { get; set; }
    public int RowVer { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I know it is possible, but not sure how. Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

When I retrieve from db in my repository (see below) I create a list of events, when I pass this list of events back via json I get a parse error due to event.UserProfile being null.
I could set it in code for each event, but that wouldn't be smart.
I need a link or an example if possible to help achieve what I need.

```
public List<Event> GetEvents(int userId, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<Event> domainList = new List<Event>();
        using (BookingModels dbEntities = new BookingModels())
        {
            var eventQuery = from dboEvents in dbEntities.Events
                             where dboEvents.Start >= start
                             && dboEvents.End <= end
                             select dboEvents;

            domainList = eventQuery.ToList<Event>();
        }

        return domainList;
    }
```

Comment: you need to adjust T4 templates, used in entity generation. On the other hand, it is interesting, why you need that?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this anyway? Isn't making the property virtual enough, if its null at least you know it hasn't been set?

Comment: Please see edit above, I hope I have explained it well enough

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I'm not experienced enough, in my opinion I wouldn't go into the trouble of manually newing up the object in the constructor because then you wouldn't know if the object was proxied via Entity Framework or not unless you actually go and check for an ID each time you need to access it, I mean you could do that, but I think it would be safer and clearer to explicitly check if its null and then create the object, also you save yourself in other situations by possibly mistakenly overwriting a current object. Could you include your json error code aswell?